# How do I call a Javascript Function from onclick event of submit button in Perl?

Tags: javascript, perl

I am trying to fire a javascript by onclick event of submit button but not able to,
Details of my code are "i have a button named filter and two text boxes which take the Id and Name,
All i want is "When i enter the value in Id textbox and click Filter then i want the values to be displayed on URL using QueryString".
here's the code..

```
    print "<td><b>UserId</b></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"User_Id\" 
        value=\"" .$Id."\"  size=\"6\" ></td>";
    print "<td><b>UserName</b></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"User_Name\"
      value=\"" .$Name  ."\" size=\"10\"></td>";
    print "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Filter\" value=\"Filter\" 
              onClick=\"FilterExpression($Id,$Name)\"></td>";
```

After i click Filter this code gets executed..

```
          if ( $q->param("Filter") )
               { 
                $Id=$q->param('User_Id');
                $Name=$q->param('User_Name');
          if ($Id ne "" )
                {
            $filterexpression= $filterexpression." UserId like '" .$Id. "%' and " ;
                }
          if ($Name ne "" )
                {
           $filterexpression= $filterexpression." UserName like '" .$Name. "%' and " ;
                }
             }
```

The Javascript..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function FilterExpression(Id,Name)
         {
          var val3=Id;
          var val4=Name
           window.location="List.cgi?Id="+val3+"&Name="+val4
           }
     </script>
```

Please Do help me out find the solution,Thank you.

Comment: You should include more details, like the values of `$Id` and `$Name`, as well as the actual HTML generated by your code.  Also, what happens when you click on the button?

Comment: can you check it, whether `$Id` and `$Name` are replacing with their values at `onClick=\"FilterExpression($Id,$Name)\"` or not?

Comment: Please include the HTML output for the function caller.  In other words, in your browser, view source and copy the html generated by `print "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Filter\" value=\"Filter\" onClick=\"FilterExpression('$Id','$Name')\"></td>";`.

Comment: i viewed the source after entering the value of Id as 1,its taking the value properly.Here it is : <td><input type="submit" name="Filter" value="Filter" onClick="FilterExpression('1','')"></td>. But i am not finding any reason for not displaying it in the URL query string.;-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you use <form> you can use method="get" is easy way.
2. If you dont want to use <form> please add "id" into

<input type=\"text\" id='User_Id' name=\"User_Id\" value=\"" .$Id."\"  size=\"6\" >

and write Javascript like this.

```
function FilterExpression()
{
var val3=document.getElementById("User_Id").value;
var val4=document.getElementById("User_Name").value;
window.location="List.cgi?Id="+val3+"&Name="+val4
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply i am using the Second Method(without using form), i edited the code "NOW AM GETTING THE VALUES IN ALERT BOX,BUT not able to send those values to URL. i.e window.location="UsersList.cgi?Id="+val3+"&Name="+val4 statement is not working,Is their any alternate way for this?Please do reply

Comment: Thank you i got the solution,its just that the action which i had specified in the form was Post instead of get.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you may need quotes.  Try `onClick=\"FilterExpression('$Id','$Name')\"`

Comment: And depending on what values `$Id` and `$Name` can take, you may need more quoting than that to avoid an XSS security vulnerability. (Think what happens if `$Name` starts with `'> <script type="text/javascript">...` - if the user can control $Name they can run arbitrary javascript for whoever views the page...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from trying to do complicated and hard to manage quotes and escapes.

If you ever have to escape quotes in a Perl program, chances are, you are doing it wrong.

Perl has [many different ways to quote strings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) that make it easy to manage strings, and fill-in variable values.  The powerful quoting operators make escaping quote characters an extreme rarity.

I'll show you a few examples.

Your example could be handled with an [interpolating here-doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF):

```
my $filter_expression = FilterExpression($Id,$Name);

print <<"END_HTML";
<td><b>UserId</b></td><td><input type="text" name="User_Id" value="$Id"  size=\"6\" ></td>"
<td><b>UserName</b></td><td><input type="text" name="User_Name" value="$Name" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Filter" value="Filter" onClick="$filter_expression"></td>
END_HTML
```

Or you could use [the `qq` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qq%2fSTRING%2f) to quote assemble your output:

```
print qq{<td><b>UserId</b></td><td><input type="text" name="User_Id" value="$Id"  size="6" ></td>};

print qq[<td><b>UserName</b></td><td><input type="text" name="User_Name" value="$Name" size="10"></td>];

print qq(<td><input type="submit" name="Filter" value="Filter" onClick=."$filter_expression"></td>);
```

Or if you insist on avoiding interpolation, simply use a [single quote](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#q%2fSTRING%2f):

```
print '<td><b>UserId</b></td><td><input type="text" name="User_Id" value="'
      .$Id
      .'"  size=\"6\" ></td>';

print '<td><b>UserName</b></td><td><input type="text" name="User_Name" value="'
      .$Name
      .'" size=\"10\"></td>';

print '<td><input type="submit" name="Filter" value="Filter"  onClick="'
      .FilterExpression($Id,$Name)
      .'"></td>';
```

Also, seriously consider using a template system to handle your HTML generation.